# How can I include a model association in a JSON response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've looked at similar posts but can't seem to quite figure it out.

I have the following function which works just fine. The Listing model has a foreign key called **price_id** which maps to the Price model and its **price_range** column. **Price_id** is returned as part of the **message** object in the JSON response.

How can I return the corresponding **price_range** value from the association instead of the **price_id** value (as part of the message obj, **and keep the other attributes**)?

```
def update
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing][:id])

    #if params were passed in for updating
    if @listing.update_attributes(params[:listing])
    #should we return the whole thing or just what's needed?
        json_response = {
             "success" => @listing.save, #save to DB and assign true/false based on success...
             "message" => @listing.attributes #USE attributes to show output the content of the @message obj, and not another object called "message"
        }

        respond_to do |format| 
            #json response
            format.html { render:json => json_response } 
            format.xml { render :xml => @listing } 

            #normal response. Consider leaving this for now?
            #format.html { render :action => "detail" } #refresh this page, with new data in it. Consider trying to use redirect instead?
            #format.xml  { head :ok }
        end
    end #end if 

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a method in your Listing model with the price_range and call it in serializable_hash

```
class Listing

  def price_range
    price.price_range
  end
end
```

Like explain on comment you can use delegate instead this method :

```
class Listing
  delegate :prince_range, :to => price
end
```

In you controller you can now do :

```
   json_response = {
         "success" => @listing.save, #save to DB and assign true/false based on success...
         "message" => @listing.serializable_hash(:methods => [:price_range])
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend using the `delegate` method instead of creating a new method yourself. `delegate :price_range, :to => :price`

Comment: @tjwallace I can see how delegate makes it available in the view. But I don't see how with the above code it will be directly appended to my "message" object along with all the other attributes. I tried it and it didn't work for me. No errors. Just wasn't there.

Comment: Worked without using delegate. Would love to use it properly, but it didn't work with (see previous comment)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I read [in this article](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/), you should be able to do this:

```
class Listing
  def as_json
    super(:include => :price)
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
json_response = {
  "success" => @listing.save,
  "message" => @listing.as_json
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. 
    ArgumentError
    in ListingsController#update
</h1>
<pre>wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)


    <div id="Application-Trace" style="display: block;">
      <pre><code>app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:70:in `update'
app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:68:in `update'</code></pre>
    </div>
    <div id="Framework-Trace" style="display: none;">
      <pre><code>activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `as_json'
activesupport (3.0.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'

[etc]

Comment: Can you print that stack trace without the markup? What was the call that caused the stack trace?

Comment: Try defining the function with the options parameter `def as_json(options={})`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add `@listing.price.price_range` value to the "message" ?
If so, try this:

```
"message" => @listing.attributes[:price_range] = @listing.price.price_range
```

Comment: I need to maintain all of the other attributes also. This overrides all of those. So this won't work for me.

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact inputs and the output that you need.